# Save multiple text areas into a downloadable .txt file keeping formatting

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project that requires the user to generate a .txt file after filling in multiple text areas. However, there is formatting (line breaks in particular) that need to be kept in these text areas. The code I've researched and adapted wraps it into a blob, which (I think) is the problem, causing the .txt to simply concatenate the contents of all text areas into a continuous line.

HTML:

```
<input id="fileInput"></input><br>
<textarea id="text1Input" cols="80" rows="25"></textarea><br>
<textarea id="text2Input" cols="80" rows="25"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="saveTextToFile()">Save Text to File</button>
```

JS:

```
function saveTextToFile() {
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("text1Input").value + "\n\ntext2Input\n\n" + document.getElementById("text2Input").value;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("fileInput").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
  }

  function destroyClickedElement(event) {
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
  }
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve the goal of generating a .txt file that maintains lines written within the text area and line breaks specified in the php concatenation?

Comment: Wrong tag?  No PHP to see here.  You have JavaScript there.

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Kevin_Kinsey. Updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blob object is OK. You don't see line breaks because `\n` is not a Windows line break and some editors don't display it. If you opened your file in Notepad++, you would see proper line breaks. Notepad however displays text concatenated.

You need to replace `\n` to `\r\n` in your Javascript. Using regex:

```
var textToSave = document.getElementById("text1Input").value.replace(/([^\r])\n/g, "$1\r\n") + "\r\n\r\ntext2Input\r\n\r\n" + document.getElementById("text2Input").value.replace(/([^\r])\n/g, "$1\r\n");
```

Comment: Thank you! Marked as correct for JS conversion fix.

Answer (score 0):

I converted your code to a runnable snippet.  To try it, click on "Show code snippet", then click the "Run code snippet" button.

When I run this snippet, I see all the line breaks I enter into the text areas.  Be aware that if you open these files with Windows Notepad, it will not show line breaks correctly.  Opening it with Window Wordpad, or some programming editor should show you the line breaks.

Maybe this isn't the answer to your question as it doesn't involve any code change, just the tool you use to examine the output.  If you want this to work with Windows Notepad, then instead of `\n`, use `\r\n`

```js
function saveTextToFile() {
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("text1Input").value + "\n\ntext2Input\n\n" + document.getElementById("text2Input").value;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("fileInput").value;

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
  }

  function destroyClickedElement(event) {
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
  }
```

```html
<input id="fileInput"></input><br>
<textarea id="text1Input" cols="80" rows="25"></textarea><br>
<textarea id="text2Input" cols="80" rows="25"></textarea><br>
<button onclick="saveTextToFile()">Save Text to File</button>
```